# How to idiomatically say that you have to quickly go to your home everyday

Tags: idiomatic-language

I got the following question in a speaking test: **What do you usually do after work?**

**Here is the answer:**

> Actually, **I have to run to my home** in order to have some sleep
>   before going to work in the morning, and unfortunately I don't have a
>   couple of hours after work because nowadays I work extra hours on
>   every weekday.

**I believe there is an idiomatic way to say "I have to run to my home" but I don't remember it. What is it?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could say something along the lines of:

- I always pop back home in the morning... / I always quickly pop back home...
- I always nip back home in the morning... / I always quickly nip back home...
- I hurry/rush back home every morning...
- I have to dash back home every morning so I can sleep

'Pop' and 'nip' are used when you go there but don't stay for very long, however they don't take into account the speed at which you get home in. 
'Rush', 'Hurry' and 'Dash' refer to the speed at which you travel but don't take into account the duration of your stay at home.

I don't believe there is a phrase that combines these two ideas, so you should simply add an adjective to describe either the speed or duration to these sentences.